# change decimal on y axis, geom_bar, "accuracy" not working

Tags: r, ggplot2, decimal, geom-bar

I would like to design a bar plot that shows the frequencies of age classes in percent on the y-axis with no decimal. I use ggplot and geom_bar.  I have read many posts but I can't remove the one decimal from the y-axis label (see pic: at the moment it is 50.0% but i want just 50%).
I tried accuracy=1, accuracy=0.01 etc., but it is not working.

I have the following code to design the bar plot:

```
myplot_age <- ggplot(data_new_fewmissing_out, aes(age)) + 
geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), fill=c("lightgreen", "blue", "black", lightblue")) + 
scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent) +
ylab("relative frequencies")+ 
theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 15),
axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15),
axis.text = element_text(size = 12, color = "black"))+
scale_x_discrete(labels=c("young", "middle", "old" ,"no answer"))
```

The results looks like the following

[bar plot with one decimal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wwSE.png)

If I apply the same code to another of my variables (e.g. farm system) it gives me no decimals so I would be grateful for a solution.
Thanks!

Comment: Not sure how you added the accuracy argument. But `scale_y_continuous(labels = ~ scales::percent(.x, accuracy = 1))` works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

`scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1)`

rather than

`scales::percent`